# Application crashes on hitting sign up button

Tags: java, android

I am using firebase to create a simple login/ sign up for an app. So far, I have only coded the sign-up function and whenever I tap it while running it, the app crashes. Related scripts are attached below.

Java code for the sign up page:

```
package com.healthandhelpapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class SignUpPage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    EditText editTextUsername, editTextPassword;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_page);

        editTextUsername=findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);
        editTextPassword=findViewById(R.id.enterPassword);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        findViewById(R.id.butSGUP).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private  void registerUser(){

        String email = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
if(email.isEmpty()){

    editTextUsername.setError("Email is required");

editTextUsername.requestFocus();
    return;
}

          if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){

editTextUsername.setError("Email is invalid");
editTextUsername.requestFocus();

          }


if (password.isEmpty()){


    editTextPassword.setError("Password is required");
    editTextPassword.requestFocus();
    return;
}


if (password.length()<7){

    editTextPassword.setError("Password is too short");
    editTextPassword.requestFocus();
}

mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }
});

    }


    @Override
    public  void onClick(View view){

        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.butSGUP:

                registerUser();

                    break;


            case R.id.tgtLogIn:

                startActivity(new Intent(this, LogInPage.class));


        }


    }



}
```

This is my app Gradle script

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.healthandhelpapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the android manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.healthandhelpapp">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".Intro">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".SignUpPage" />
            <activity android:name=".LogInPage"></activity>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

And lastly, this is the xml script for the sign up page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#699dee"
    tools:context=".SignUpPage">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="287dp"
        android:layout_height="147dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Welcome! Since you have not yet registered enter your E-Mail Address and password in the respective fields below."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="222dp"
        android:background="#699"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="E-Mail Address"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textColorHint="#fff" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/enterPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="155dp"
        android:background="#699"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColorHint="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butSGUP"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:background="#f2f2f5"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Sign Up" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tgtLogIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:text="Already have an account; Log In from here" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: here is the highighted part of the log I got from a debug

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.healthandhelpapp, PID: 14754
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                  at com.healthandhelpapp.SignUpPage.registerUser(SignUpPage.java:38)
                  at com.healthandhelpapp.SignUpPage.onClick(SignUpPage.java:91)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6367)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25032)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

EDIT 2: I have added the permissions and changed the edit text problem. now it doesnt crash, but the fucntion stilld doesnt run, i.e. the user does not get registred

Comment: can you post your error ?

Comment: Please post error log while you are asking crash related questions because most of the times answer lies there.

Comment: @kdblue I have edited the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) you need to add Internet permission in manifest

2)

```
editTextUsername=findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);
        editTextPassword=findViewById(R.id.enteredPassword);
```

replace to :-

```
editTextUsername=findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);
            editTextPassword=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

**Note** :- You are getting Nullpointer Exception because of its not finding views in your xml .

I hope this solve your problem !

Comment: This seems to be it. It doesnt exactly work; I doesnt crash any more, but the function doesnt run i.e. the user does not register. Edit: I try to run a debugger but I got this "Error running 'app': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8600): java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused: connect" "

Comment: have taken internet permission in menifest ?

Comment: I have. Also edited the code for all the changes i made

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Add an `INTERNET` permission in your manifest.

Hopefully that is your error.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing permissions on your manifest file.
Put this in...

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> ```
>
> If something else went wrong, please append logs.

Correct this...

.................

```
public class SignUpPage extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {


private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
```

> ```
> private EditText editTextUsername, editTextPassword;
> ```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up_page);

    editTextUsername=findViewById(R.id.enterEmail);
```

> ```
>     editTextPassword=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
> ```

```
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    findViewById(R.id.butSGUP).setOnClickListener(this);
}

private  void registerUser(){
```

....................

If not this, then initialize them on every function you call. I don't if it's a bug or something, but I've experienced the same thing several times.

Comment: I added the permission but I doesn't seem to help

Comment: I see... you should either declare your edittext as private or initialize it every step you're invoking it.  That should solve the problem. I'm editing my answer with your code corrected!

Answer (score 0):

You should change `if(email.isEmpty())`, to `if(email.getText().toString().equals(""))`. I think that as it is now, it always returns false and hence goes in the `else` code. And therefore you get the `NullPointerException` when trying to get the string of the `EditText`.

Does the error always happen or is it only when the click event happens when the `EditText` is blank?